# objective C background only applications NSAlert message on top of all other windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I have a objective C background only application .At some point of stage i have to pop up an NSAlert message.The alert message is displaying properly but i have to minimize so many open windows(applications folder or any other folder window) and other applications window to see the NSAlert window .

Is there any way to bring it up . I have to support 10.5+ .
I tried with the following ways .But nothing worked
1. [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoreingOtherApps:YES];
2. SetFrontProcessWithOptions(&myPSN,0);
3.SetFrontProcess(&myPSN)

Please help .

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
[myWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

this will put the myWindow on top of all other windows even in all spaces!!!